# r loop optimisation (getMinBBox with sf and data.table)

Tags: r, data.table, r-sf

I have some question how to speed up my code.

I have a shp with more than 100000 polygons and I want calculate minimal bounding box for each of them. I found some code for this part here: https://rdrr.io/cran/flightplanning/src/R/utils.R

Code calculate min bounding box from coordinates in matrix form for one poylgon at time.

I use loop and data.table but for bigger shp (50000+ polygons) is this process really time consuming.

Is maybe possible use getMinBBox() with lapply inside data.table?

thank you

my code:

```
library(sf)
library(data.table)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))[1:4,]
nc

nc=st_cast(nc,"POLYGON")
cor=as.data.frame(st_coordinates(nc))
cor
setDT(cor)
setDT(nc)
data <- data.table(width=numeric(), height=numeric())

for(i in 1:nrow(nc)){
    l=as.matrix(cor[L2==i,1:2])
    l=getMinBBox(l)
    data=rbind(data,t(l[2:3]))}

nc=cbind(nc,data)
nc


## execution time for each part of code inside loop
library(microbenchmark)
mb=microbenchmark(
l<-as.matrix(cor[L2==1,1:2]),
ll<-getMinBBox(l),
data<-rbind(data,t(ll[2:3]))
)

Unit: microseconds
                              expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval cld
 l <- as.matrix(cor[L2 == 1, 1:2]) 2144.7 2478.40 2606.981 2574.05 2711.55 4396.3   100   c
               ll <- getMinBBox(l)  885.3  976.05 1050.203 1054.10 1103.55 1788.3   100  b 
   data <- rbind(data, t(ll[2:3]))  152.6  182.95  207.617  201.60  224.05  546.1   100 a  




## getMinBBox code from https://rdrr.io/cran/flightplanning/src/R/utils.R


getMinBBox <- function(xy) {
  stopifnot(is.matrix(xy), is.numeric(xy), nrow(xy) >= 2, ncol(xy) == 2)

  ## rotating calipers algorithm using the convex hull
  H    <- grDevices::chull(xy)      ## hull indices, vertices ordered clockwise
  n    <- length(H)      ## number of hull vertices
  hull <- xy[H, ]        ## hull vertices

  ## unit basis vectors for all subspaces spanned by the hull edges
  hDir  <- diff(rbind(hull, hull[1, ])) ## hull vertices are circular
  hLens <- sqrt(rowSums(hDir^2))        ## length of basis vectors
  huDir <- diag(1/hLens) %*% hDir       ## scaled to unit length

  ## unit basis vectors for the orthogonal subspaces
  ## rotation by 90 deg -> y' = x, x' = -y
  ouDir <- cbind(-huDir[ , 2], huDir[ , 1])

  ## project hull vertices on the subspaces spanned by the hull edges, and on
  ## the subspaces spanned by their orthogonal complements - in subspace coords
  projMat <- rbind(huDir, ouDir) %*% t(hull)

  ## range of projections and corresponding width/height of bounding rectangle
  rangeH  <- matrix(numeric(n*2), ncol=2)  ## hull edge
  rangeO  <- matrix(numeric(n*2), ncol=2)  ## orthogonal subspace
  widths  <- numeric(n)
  heights <- numeric(n)

  for(i in seq(along=numeric(n))) {
    rangeH[i, ] <- range(projMat[  i, ])

    ## the orthogonal subspace is in the 2nd half of the matrix
    rangeO[i, ] <- range(projMat[n+i, ])
    widths[i]   <- abs(diff(rangeH[i, ]))
    heights[i]  <- abs(diff(rangeO[i, ]))
  }

  ## extreme projections for min-area rect in subspace coordinates
  ## hull edge leading to minimum-area
  eMin  <- which.min(widths*heights)
  hProj <- rbind(   rangeH[eMin, ], 0)
  oProj <- rbind(0, rangeO[eMin, ])

  ## move projections to rectangle corners
  hPts <- sweep(hProj, 1, oProj[ , 1], "+")
  oPts <- sweep(hProj, 1, oProj[ , 2], "+")

  ## corners in standard coordinates, rows = x,y, columns = corners
  ## in combined (4x2)-matrix: reverse point order to be usable in polygon()
  ## basis formed by hull edge and orthogonal subspace
  basis <- cbind(huDir[eMin, ], ouDir[eMin, ])
  hCorn <- basis %*% hPts
  oCorn <- basis %*% oPts
  pts   <- t(cbind(hCorn, oCorn[ , c(2, 1)]))

  ## angle of longer edge pointing up
  dPts <- diff(pts)
  e    <- dPts[which.max(rowSums(dPts^2)), ] ## one of the longer edges
  eUp  <- e * sign(e[2])       ## rotate upwards 180 deg if necessary
  deg  <- atan2(eUp[2], eUp[1])*180 / pi     ## angle in degrees

  return(list(pts=pts, width=heights[eMin], height=widths[eMin], angle=deg))
}

#' Provided an angle, calculate the corresponding minimum bounding box
#'
#' @param vertices the vertices which to get the bounding box from
#' @param alpha the angle to rotate the bounding box
#'
#' @importFrom grDevices chull
getBBoxAngle = function(vertices, alpha) {
  centroid = apply(vertices, 2, mean)

  angleRadians = (90-alpha) * pi/180

  rotatedX = cos(angleRadians) * (vertices[, 1] - centroid[1]) -
             sin(angleRadians) * (vertices[, 2] - centroid[2]) +
             centroid[1]
  rotatedY = sin(angleRadians) * (vertices[, 1] - centroid[1]) +
             cos(angleRadians) * (vertices[, 2] - centroid[2]) +
             centroid[2]

  bBox = cbind(range(rotatedX), range(rotatedY))
  height = diff(bBox[,2])
  width = diff(bBox[,1])

  bBox = rbind(bBox[1,],
               c(bBox[1, 1], bBox[2, 2]),
               (bBox[2, ]),
               c(bBox[2, 1], bBox[1, 2]))

  bBoxUnrotatedX = cos(-angleRadians) * (bBox[, 1] - centroid[1]) -
                   sin(-angleRadians) * (bBox[, 2] - centroid[2]) +
                   centroid[1]
  bBoxUnrotatedY = sin(-angleRadians) * (bBox[, 1] - centroid[1]) +
                   cos(-angleRadians) * (bBox[, 2] - centroid[2]) +
                   centroid[2]
  unrotatedBbox = cbind(bBoxUnrotatedX, bBoxUnrotatedY)
  list(angle=alpha, height=height, width=width, pts=unrotatedBbox)
}

#' Given a xy matrix of points, adjust the
#' points to avoid acute angles < 80 degrees
#'
#' @param xy xy dataframe
#' @param angle angle of the flight lines
#' @param minAngle the minimum angle to below which will be projected
adjustAcuteAngles = function(xy, angle, minAngle = 80) {
  xy_mat = as.matrix(xy[,1:2])
  rads = angle*pi/180
  nPoints = nrow(xy)

  # Using cosine rule on vectors
  # acos(theta) = (AB_vec x BC_vec) / (|AB| * |BC|)
  vectors = xy[-1,]-xy[-nPoints,]

  # Final angles for each point
  angles = getAngles(xy_mat)

  # Mask angles less than minimum
  mask = angles <= minAngle
  mask[is.na(mask)] = FALSE
  # Index of point with angles less than minimum
  indices = (seq_along(mask)+1)[mask]

  indicesOffset = (indices %% 2 == 1) * 2 - 1

  # Calculate perpendicular lines for points
  x = xy[indices, 1]
  y = xy[indices, 2]
  nIndices = length(indices)
  a = rep(tan(rads), nIndices)
  b = y - a * x
  a_perpendicular = -1/a
  b_perpendicular = y - a_perpendicular*x


  b2 = b_perpendicular
  a2 = a_perpendicular

  # Intersect previous straight line with the perpendicular
  x = xy[indices-indicesOffset, 1]
  y = xy[indices-indicesOffset, 2]
  a1 = a
  b1 = y - a1 * x
  xs = (b2-b1)/(a1-a2)
  ys = a2*xs+b2

  # Replace angled points
  xy[indices-indicesOffset, 1] = xs
  xy[indices-indicesOffset, 2] = ys
  return(xy)
}

#' Create outer curves for the flight lines
#'
#' @param waypoints the waypoints of the flight plan
#' @param angle angle for the flight lines
#' @param flightLineDistance the distance between the flight lines in meters
outerCurvePoints = function(waypoints, angle, flightLineDistance) {
  mask = getAngles(waypoints) == 180
  mask[is.na(mask)] = TRUE

  rads = angle*pi/180
  angularCoef = tan(rads)
  nWaypoints = nrow(waypoints)

  oddPoints = seq(1, nWaypoints, 2)
  evenPoints = seq(2, nWaypoints, 2)

  offsetX = waypoints[evenPoints,1]-waypoints[oddPoints,1]

  intercept = waypoints[oddPoints, 2] - angularCoef*waypoints[oddPoints, 1]
  xMove = rep(flightLineDistance / sqrt(1 + angularCoef**2), nWaypoints)
  isNegative = rep(offsetX < 0, each=2)
  isNegative[seq(1, nWaypoints, 2)] = !isNegative[seq(1, nWaypoints, 2)]
  xMove[isNegative] = -xMove[isNegative]
  yMove = xMove * angularCoef

  xs = waypoints[, 1] + xMove
  ys = waypoints[, 2] + yMove

  curvePoints = as.data.frame(cbind(xs, ys))
  curvePoints$index = seq(1, nWaypoints)
  curvePoints$before = (curvePoints$index %% 2) == 1
  curvePoints = curvePoints[!c(FALSE, mask),]

  return(curvePoints)
}

#' Get angles for each point considering
#' the two neighbors points
#'
#' @param waypoints the waypoints of the flight plan
getAngles = function(waypoints) {
  nPoints = nrow(waypoints)
  vectors = waypoints[-1,]-waypoints[-nPoints,]
  dists = sqrt(apply(vectors ** 2, 1, sum))

  ab = vectors[-nPoints+1,]
  bc = vectors[-1,]
  dist_ab = dists[-nPoints+1]
  dist_bc = dists[-1]
  dotProds = sapply(seq_len(nPoints-2), function(x) ab[x,] %*% bc[x,])
  # Final angles for each point
  angles = suppressWarnings(180-round(acos(dotProds/(dist_ab*dist_bc))*180/pi,2))
  angles
}

#' Class for Flight Parameters
setClass("Flight Parameters",
         slots = c(
           flight.line.distance  = "numeric",
           flight.speed.kmh      = "numeric",
           front.overlap         = "numeric",
           gsd                   = "numeric",
           height                = "numeric",
           ground.height         = "numeric",
           minimum.shutter.speed = "character",
           photo.interval        = "numeric"
         ),
         prototype = list(
           flight.line.distance  = NA_real_,
           flight.speed.kmh      = NA_real_,
           front.overlap         = NA_real_,
           gsd                   = NA_real_,
           ground.height         = NA_real_,
           height                = NA_real_,
           minimum.shutter.speed = NA_character_,
           photo.interval        = NA_real_
         )
)
```

Comment: If 99% of the time in your loop is in the code that finds the minimum bounding box (which I guess is about right) then there's no point changing it to use `lapply` rather than `for` since the best you can do is scrape off that remaining 1%. You need a faster function to compute the minBBox.

Comment: I added microbenchmark for each part of code inside loop and getMinBBox its not so slow. But I am not sure if this is the right way to do microbenchmark?

Comment: Figuring out where a script is spending its time is "profiing", not benchmarking. See `help(Rprof)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code is so small that some approaches might only be faster if you were looking at larger data.tables. It seems to me that you could shave some time off by doing a split-combine approach, which, in principle, you could run in parallel, e.g. by using `mclapply` instead of `lapply` (on linux/macos). You are probably also a bit faster if you use `rbindlist` rather than `rbind` and transpose.
On my machine this approach almost halves the execution time on this tiny set. Using `mclapply(co, gmb2, mc.cores=4L)` or similar may be beneficial if the individual L2 groups are larger, but only hurts performance with this small dataset.
Short of changing the code of the `getMinBBox` function, this would at least reduce the time somewhat and may be worth a try.

As a side note: using openblas or Intel's MKL instead of the default R libraries can make a big difference in the matrix calculations, so you should definitely make sure you use those.

```r
# function code
    getMinBBox <- function(xy) {
        stopifnot(is.matrix(xy), is.numeric(xy), nrow(xy) >= 2, ncol(xy) == 2)

        ## rotating calipers algorithm using the convex hull
        H    <- grDevices::chull(xy)      ## hull indices, vertices ordered clockwise
        n    <- length(H)      ## number of hull vertices
        hull <- xy[H, ]        ## hull vertices

        ## unit basis vectors for all subspaces spanned by the hull edges
        hDir  <- diff(rbind(hull, hull[1, ])) ## hull vertices are circular
        hLens <- sqrt(rowSums(hDir^2))        ## length of basis vectors
        huDir <- diag(1/hLens) %*% hDir       ## scaled to unit length

        ## unit basis vectors for the orthogonal subspaces
        ## rotation by 90 deg -> y' = x, x' = -y
        ouDir <- cbind(-huDir[ , 2], huDir[ , 1])

        ## project hull vertices on the subspaces spanned by the hull edges, and on
        ## the subspaces spanned by their orthogonal complements - in subspace coords
        projMat <- rbind(huDir, ouDir) %*% t(hull)

        ## range of projections and corresponding width/height of bounding rectangle
        rangeH  <- matrix(numeric(n*2), ncol=2)  ## hull edge
        rangeO  <- matrix(numeric(n*2), ncol=2)  ## orthogonal subspace
        widths  <- numeric(n)
        heights <- numeric(n)

        for(i in seq(along=numeric(n))) {
            rangeH[i, ] <- range(projMat[  i, ])

            ## the orthogonal subspace is in the 2nd half of the matrix
            rangeO[i, ] <- range(projMat[n+i, ])
            widths[i]   <- abs(diff(rangeH[i, ]))
            heights[i]  <- abs(diff(rangeO[i, ]))
        }

        ## extreme projections for min-area rect in subspace coordinates
        ## hull edge leading to minimum-area
        eMin  <- which.min(widths*heights)
        hProj <- rbind(   rangeH[eMin, ], 0)
        oProj <- rbind(0, rangeO[eMin, ])

        ## move projections to rectangle corners
        hPts <- sweep(hProj, 1, oProj[ , 1], "+")
        oPts <- sweep(hProj, 1, oProj[ , 2], "+")

        ## corners in standard coordinates, rows = x,y, columns = corners
        ## in combined (4x2)-matrix: reverse point order to be usable in polygon()
        ## basis formed by hull edge and orthogonal subspace
        basis <- cbind(huDir[eMin, ], ouDir[eMin, ])
        hCorn <- basis %*% hPts
        oCorn <- basis %*% oPts
        pts   <- t(cbind(hCorn, oCorn[ , c(2, 1)]))

        ## angle of longer edge pointing up
        dPts <- diff(pts)
        e    <- dPts[which.max(rowSums(dPts^2)), ] ## one of the longer edges
        eUp  <- e * sign(e[2])       ## rotate upwards 180 deg if necessary
        deg  <- atan2(eUp[2], eUp[1])*180 / pi     ## angle in degrees

        return(list(pts=pts, width=heights[eMin], height=widths[eMin], angle=deg))
    }

#> Reading layer `nc' from data source `/home/b/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/sf/shape/nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
            height                = NA_real_,
            minimum.shutter.speed = NA_character_,
            photo.interval        = NA_real_
        )
    )


# common code:
lapply(c("sf", "data.table", "microbenchmark"),
    require, character.only = TRUE)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))[1:4,]
nc <- st_cast(nc,"POLYGON")
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(nc, "POLYGON"): repeating attributes for all sub-
#> geometries for which they may not be constant
coor <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(nc))
setDT(coor)
setDT(nc)

# your code (wrapped in a function):
getbox1 <- function(){
    data <- data.table(width=numeric(), height=numeric())
    for(i in 1:nrow(nc)){
        l=as.matrix(coor[L2==i,1:2])
        ll=getMinBBox(l)
        data=rbind(data,t(ll[2:3]))}
    data
}

## split - apply code:
gmb2 <- function(i) getMinBBox(as.matrix(i[,1:2]))[c(2:3)]
getbox2 <- function(){
    co <- split(coor, coor$L2)
    rbindlist(lapply(co, gmb2))
}

microbenchmark(b1 = getbox1(), b2 = getbox2())
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>    b1 7.804903 8.391429 20.539996 9.870947 38.71889 66.95236   100   b
#>    b2 3.956369 4.186426  9.919638 4.562312 19.13847 47.27808   100  a
```

A final edit: You can squeeze some more performance out of the getMinBBox function by simplifying it a bit.

```r
# original function code (removed some comments for brevity)
getMinBBox <- function(xy) {
    stopifnot(is.matrix(xy), is.numeric(xy), nrow(xy) >= 2, ncol(xy) == 2)
    H    <- grDevices::chull(xy)      ## hull indices, vertices ordered clockwise
    n    <- length(H)      ## number of hull vertices
    hull <- xy[H, ]        ## hull vertices
    hDir  <- diff(rbind(hull, hull[1, ])) ## hull vertices are circular
    hLens <- sqrt(rowSums(hDir^2))        ## length of basis vectors
    huDir <- diag(1/hLens) %*% hDir       ## scaled to unit length
    ouDir <- cbind(-huDir[ , 2], huDir[ , 1])
    projMat <- rbind(huDir, ouDir) %*% t(hull)
    rangeH  <- matrix(numeric(n*2), ncol=2)  ## hull edge
    rangeO  <- matrix(numeric(n*2), ncol=2)  ## orthogonal subspace
    widths  <- numeric(n)
    heights <- numeric(n)
    for(i in seq(along=numeric(n))) {
        rangeH[i, ] <- range(projMat[  i, ])
        rangeO[i, ] <- range(projMat[n+i, ])
        widths[i]   <- abs(diff(rangeH[i, ]))
        heights[i]  <- abs(diff(rangeO[i, ]))
    }
    eMin  <- which.min(widths*heights)
    hProj <- rbind(   rangeH[eMin, ], 0)
    oProj <- rbind(0, rangeO[eMin, ])
    hPts <- sweep(hProj, 1, oProj[ , 1], "+")
    oPts <- sweep(hProj, 1, oProj[ , 2], "+")
    basis <- cbind(huDir[eMin, ], ouDir[eMin, ])
    hCorn <- basis %*% hPts
    oCorn <- basis %*% oPts
    pts   <- t(cbind(hCorn, oCorn[ , c(2, 1)]))
    dPts <- diff(pts)
    e    <- dPts[which.max(rowSums(dPts^2)), ] ## one of the longer edges
    eUp  <- e * sign(e[2])       ## rotate upwards 180 deg if necessary
    deg  <- atan2(eUp[2], eUp[1])*180 / pi     ## angle in degrees
    return(list(pts=pts, width=heights[eMin], height=widths[eMin], angle=deg))
}


# common code:
lapply(c("sf", "data.table", "microbenchmark", "compiler"),
    require, character.only = TRUE)
compiler::enableJIT(3)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))[1:4,]
nc <- st_cast(nc,"POLYGON")
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(nc, "POLYGON"): repeating attributes for all sub-
#> geometries for which they may not be constant
coor <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(nc))
setDT(coor)
setDT(nc)

getMinBBox2 <- function(xy) {
    # stopifnot(is.matrix(xy), is.numeric(xy), nrow(xy) >= 2, ncol(xy) == 2)
    # skip checking
    H    <- grDevices::chull(xy)      ## hull indices, vertices ordered clockwise
    n    <- length(H)      ## number of hull vertices
    hull <- xy[H, ]        ## hull vertices
    hDir <- matrixStats::colDiffs(rbind(hull, hull[1, ]))
    hLens <- sqrt(rowSums(hDir^2))        ## length of basis vectors
    huDir <- diag(1/hLens) %*% hDir       ## scaled to unit length
    ouDir <- cbind(-huDir[ , 2], huDir[ , 1])
    projMat <- tcrossprod(rbind(huDir, ouDir), hull)
    HO <- list(seq_len(n), (seq_len(n)+n))
    rr <- matrixStats::rowRanges(projMat)
    rd <- as.numeric(matrixStats::rowDiffs(rr))
    rangeH <- rr[HO[[1]],]
    rangeO <- rr[HO[[2]],]
    widths <- rd[HO[[1]]]
    heights <- rd[HO[[2]]]
    eMin  <- which.min(widths*heights)
    ## seems like sweeping is not required here?
    # hProj <- rbind(   rangeH[eMin, ], 0)
    # oProj <- rbind(0, rangeO[eMin, ])
    # hPts <- sweep(hProj, 1, oProj[ , 1], "+")
    # oPts <- sweep(hProj, 1, oProj[ , 2], "+")
    hPts <- rbind(rangeH[eMin, ], rep(rangeO[eMin, 1], 2))
    oPts <- rbind(rangeH[eMin, ], rep(rangeO[eMin, 2], 2))
    basis <- cbind(huDir[eMin, ], ouDir[eMin, ])
    hCorn <- basis %*% hPts
    oCorn <- basis %*% oPts
    pts   <- t(cbind(hCorn, oCorn[ , c(2, 1)]))
    colnames(pts) <- c("X", "Y")
    dPts <- diff(pts)
    e    <- dPts[which.max(rowSums(dPts^2)), ] ## one of the longer edges
    eUp  <- e * sign(e[2])       ## rotate upwards 180 deg if necessary
    deg  <- atan2(eUp[2], eUp[1])*180 / pi     ## angle in degrees
    return(list(pts=pts, width=heights[eMin], height=widths[eMin], angle=deg))
}

# your code (wrapped in a function):
getbox1 <- function(){
    data <- data.table(width=numeric(), height=numeric())
    for(i in 1:nrow(nc)){
        l=as.matrix(coor[L2==i,1:2])
        ll=getMinBBox(l)
        data=rbind(data,t(ll[2:3]))}
    data
}

## split - apply code:
gmb2 <- function(i) getMinBBox(as.matrix(i[,1:2]))[c(2:3)]
gmb3 <- function(i) getMinBBox2(as.matrix(i[,1:2]))[c(2:3)]
getbox2 <- function(){
    co <- split(coor, coor$L2)
    rbindlist(lapply(co, gmb2))
}
getbox3 <- function(){
    co <- split(coor, coor$L2)
    rbindlist(lapply(co, gmb3))
}

all(identical(getbox1(), getbox2()), identical(getbox2(), getbox3()))
#> [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(b1 = getbox1(), b2 = getbox2(), b3=getbox3())
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#>    b1 7.852630 8.067991 8.862175 8.269768 8.632328 14.474924   100   c
#>    b2 4.020513 4.071012 4.444000 4.166884 4.274048  7.728204   100  b 
#>    b3 2.871639 2.938294 3.111886 2.986174 3.046096  5.935133   100 a
```

Comment: thank you, with your code its quite fast. Its interesting that split take almost 2/5 of time (shp with 270000 polygons).

Answer (score 0):

yesterday I found a little different approach to solving my problem with package - parallel. It is really fast way but I cannot find how to write length and width in its own column.

```
library(lidR)
library(sf) 
library(raster)
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))[1:4,]
nc

setDT(nc)

overFun <- function(x){
  unlist(getMinBBox(as.matrix(st_coordinates(x)[,1:2]))[2:3])
}


cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(cl, list("getMinBBox","st_coordinates","data.table"))
nc[,c("width","length"):=.(clusterMap(cl, overFun, nc$geometry)),]
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Weird... I don't gain anything from running it in parallel, as mentioned before. To get length and width as separate columns, you could do: `overFun2 <- function(x){setNames(getMinBBox2(st_coordinates(x)[,1:2])[2:3], c("width", "height"))}; data.table(nc, as.data.table(t(mcmapply( overFun2, nc$geometry, mc.cores= (detectCores() - 1)))))` (or the equivalent with `clusterMap` if you are on Windows).